# XPath parsing gives me an error

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the first image from [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Akali) site but I keep getting an error and can't quite figure out why..

Here's the code:

```
string pictureurl = webdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[2]/table[1]/tr/td/a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```

and the error is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Can anyone please tell me why? if I remove the above line it works fine..

Comment: Have tried breaking the line down into individual parts to discover which bit is returning `null`?

Comment: Does the third `div` in the page (from _all_ `div`s) have two tables? Does the second table have the first cell with an `a` element?

Comment: Use the debugger and hover your mouse over parts of the line to find out what's null.

Comment: @codesparkle - Not really going to work with a single XPath expression like that.

Comment: Chances are `SelectSingleNode` is returning `null`... are there namespaces involved by any chance?

Comment: Note that XPath indexes are one-based. div[2] will return second div and table[1] the first table. Check if that's what you are expecting.

Comment: you say that you want to get img but your xpath is getting a hyperlink

Comment: Well, I found the problem.. It works for Akali, but doesn't for Ahri. The wiki pages are inconsistent and I'd need a different one for each page :| Is there another way of solving this?

Comment: @argoneus what exactly are you after it seems you asked and you answered it to yourself

Comment: I just wanted to get a link of the image for each of the sites, but they don't all have the same format, what should I do?

Comment: @argoneus do you mean the src of an image?

Comment: I mean the layout in general. In some, the image is in div[1] in others its somewhere else.. :|

Comment: @argoneus why not just get img like this with xpath "//img" this will get you all the img's of the document

Comment: when I tried that, //img[1] was something else, //img[2] too and //img[3] crashed with the above error message >.>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14226/discussion-between-argoneus-and-hatsoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is not correct to get a img

please use this way

```
string pictureurl = 
webdoc.DocumentNode
.SelectSingleNode("//div[2]/table[1]/tr/td/a/img")
.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `//div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a`. Depending on the configuration settings HtmlAgilityPack inserts a tbody element.

Answer (score 1):

Double check through the debugger that the following actually returns something...

```
webdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[2]/table[1]/tr/td/a");
```

My guess is not, and instead use the following (note the extra `tbody`)..

```
webdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a");
```